# Old firefox profiles as Firefox uses snap now in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, snap, .profile

I've just migrated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
My firefox profile was previously located in the .mozilla/firefox home folder.
Now I can see there is also a profile in the same name in snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox.

When opening the`about:profiles`, I can see this is now the snap one which is used.

Does it mean that I can remove the .mozilla/firefox folder?

Thanks for your help

Kind regards

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with the new Firefox as it is, then yes, you can delete the old folder. However you may have some important saved password or other info in the old Firefox directory, consider to backup it, instead of deleting.

If you have just started to use the new snap version and you want to have your previous Firefox settings you also can move the old directory to the new place (when Firefox is not running).

Comment: The snap migration copies all of the old profile directory.  That is why the snap profile is "in the same name".